# C++ modulus small program issue

Tags: c++, modulus

I'm trying to write a very simple program in C++ that finds the modulus of two numbers as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int d;
int modulus;
int main()
{
cout<<"***Welcome to the MODULUS calculator***";
cout<<"Enter the numerator, then press ENTER: ";
cin>>n;
cout<<"Enter the denominator, then press ENTER: ";
cin>>d;
modulus=n%d;
cout<<"The modulus is ---> "<<modulus;
return 0;
}
```

But, when I try to compile it, I get the following:

[image]

How can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you *read* the error messages?

Comment: I looked at part of the messages but didn't get what is needed to tackle the issue.

Comment: I guess you have to understand what the compiler is trying to tell you. The message is rather straightforward.

Comment: @sharptooth. I moved "int modulus;" inside "int main()" and it worked. But, why? Why should I make it local to the main() method? Thanks.

Comment: Its scope changed, so it no longer conflicts with the struct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the error because the name of your global variable `modulus` clashes with `std::modulus`. To fix this, you can:

- Make `modulus` a local variable
- Rename the `modulus` variable
- Remove `using namespace std` and either import the names you need from `std` individually or qualify them with `std::`

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `using namespace std;` it clashes with [std::modulus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/modulus/)

Corrected version:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout<<"***Welcome to the MODULUS calculator***";

    cout<<"Enter the numerator, then press ENTER: ";
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"Enter the denominator, then press ENTER: ";
    int d;
    cin>>d;

    int modulus=n%d;

    cout<<"The modulus is ---> "<<modulus;
    return 0;
}
```